# How do I install a nice notification indicator for the keyboard layout?

Tags: indicator, keyboard-layout, notification-area

I am used to changing often my keyboard layout. Therefore I can easily use the indicator in the notification area.

However it does not look very nice, because of its colors. Is there a mean to replace it by a 'mono-colored' indicator, for the Ambiance and for the Radiance themes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-ubuntu/+bug/628015/comments/9) that should be fixed in the next release, in the meantime
 there is a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-ubuntu/+bug/628015/comments/9):

> Included in the tarball are the 246 iso country coded "flag" icons for the keyboard indicator in 22px size for a dark panel background. Each of these flags consists of a box with the two letters of the iso code inside.
>
> By untarring this archive into `~/.icons/` should create a folder called `flags` containing all of the files.
>
> Next run in the terminal:
>
> ```
> gconftool-2 --type boolean --set /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/indicator/showFlags "True"
> ```
>
> Which will enable keyboard indicator flags.

The tarball mentioned above: [flags.tar.bz2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-ubuntu/+bug/628015/+attachment/1729255/+files/flags.tar.bz2)

[image: Screenshot of keyboard layout indicator]

Flag icons for the Faenza icon set: [[Default]](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Language+Flags+for+Faenza+and+Elementary?content=133726) [[Dark Panel]](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Language+Flags+for+Faenza+Dark+Panel?content=133910)

Comment: I think installing the `famfamfam-flag-png` package is much easier

Answer (score 0):

[KKBSwitch](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/kkbswitch) is the closest I could find. It's an icon that sits in your system tray, allowing you to switch layouts quickly.

I could've sworn there used to be a GNOME Panel applet for this. I don't know where it went.