# How can I see my keyboard layout in the panel?

Tags: 10.10, indicator, gnome-panel, keyboard-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install a nice notification indicator for the keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14228/how-do-i-install-a-nice-notification-indicator-for-the-keyboard-layout)

how can I see my keyboard layout in the panel in ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/14228/3940

Answer (score 2):

From 10.10 the keyboard indicator applet is shown in the panel as soon as more than one layout was defined. For additional hints on configuration see also [@Stefano Palazzo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10223/display-current-layout-language-code-country-flag-in-keyboard-indicator/10268#10268) to a similar question.