# How could I see the keyboard layout in Xfce?

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce

In Gnome keyboard settings, there's a window in which you can see the layout, a keyboard with buttons and characters on them like this:

[image]

In XFCE (Xubuntu 12.04) there's no such program.

What can I install to see it?

Comment: Great question. Let me know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install xkeycaps
```

Launch `xkeycaps` in a terminal

Comment: This program does show a keyboard layout, but it doesn't automatically show the currently used keyboard layout. User must have the knowledge to manually select the vendor, keyboard and its layout.

Comment: I found that this was quite difficult to use.  I didn't know which physical keyboard and layout I had to select.  And I couldn't see my layout (Dvorak) as an option.  Then it borked my current layout.  Plugging in a USB keyboard reverted/reset back to what I had.

Answer (score 0):

In XFCE it is possible to install Gnome Panel applications. If native panel application is not available in XFCE, you can consider adding the Gnome Panel Application that does the same job.

Comment: Here - check these links:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/25955/how-can-i-see-my-keyboard-layout-in-the-panel
http://askubuntu.com/questions/14228/how-do-i-install-a-nice-notification-indicator-for-the-keyboard-layout

By the way, I just googled for you!

Comment: No, it's not what I look for. I already have a layout notification widget. I need to see the keyboard layout itself. See the updated question.